Butyl tape for roof shield?
I am roofing my shed, and using felt underlayment. We don’t get a ton of snow, but sometimes we get some. I don’t feel like buying a giant roll of expensive ice and water shield for the eaves, And I was wondering if some window flashing tape under the drip edge on the eaves would be a decent substitute. I could go with 6 inches or 12 inches, And fold about an inch over the edge to cover the plywood sheathing and a little bit of the facia.

Are you heating the shed? If not, you should not have any ice dam issues, and the usual treatment of a shed roof (in my area) would be two layers of felt at the edge and revisit in 20-25 years when the whole roof needs replacing.
Flashing tape is indeed pretty much the same thing as ice and water shield, in a smaller format, so if you'd like to do that, you can. But it's unlikely to change anything about the life of the roof on an unheated shed.
For a heated shed, the same things that prevent ice dams on houses work on sheds- adequate insulation with adequate clear venting space above to maintain a cold roof. People often skimp "because it's just a shed" and then there will be problems (both cost of heating and ice dams.)
